# Sql server and R: How to make Fetch process quick

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, rodbc

I'm trying to run the following query by connecting to SQL server through RODBC package.

```
p <- sqlQuery(con, 'SELECT ACCT_TYP1, svc_cnct_dt,
          acct_sts_cd,
          suit_filed_sts,
          settlement_sts,
          CLIENT_ID,
          ZIP,
          ST,
          high_crd_bucket,
sum(count) as count,
sum(curr_bal) as curr_bal,
sum(high_crd) as high_crd
FROM DM_STMP.dbo.TEMP_Accounts_May_2017
GROUP BY ACCT_TYP1, svc_cnct_dt,
          acct_sts_cd,
          suit_filed_sts,
          settlement_sts,
          CLIENT_ID,
          ZIP,
          ST,
          high_crd_bucket')
```

This is taking me enormous time(Even after limiting the rows to 1000).

When I accessed the top 10 rows of the database with same 9 columns results are the following

```
user  system elapsed 
0.03    0.00    0.06 

system.time(p <- sqlQuery(con, 'SELECT TOP(10) 
         ACCT_TYP1,
         svc_cnct_dt,
         acct_sts_cd,
         suit_filed_sts,
         settlement_sts,
         CLIENT_ID,
         ZIP,
         ST,
         high_crd_bucket 

         FROM DM_STMP.dbo.TEMP_Accounts_May_2017'
 ))
```

The database TEMP_Accounts_May_2017 contains 6000000 rows. I am using Windows 7, 64-bit system with R version 3.4.0.
Can anyone tell me what's possibly going wrong?